# Login with python to scrape pages

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

I need to scrape a page that requires login to access. But I couldn't do it for this web page. How can I do that?

I want to login on 'https://web.tvplus.com.tr/giris' And then scrape pages like: 'https://web.tvplus.com.tr/kanallar'

I haven't tried anything for the question. I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow typically hates questions like these, but the book I used when I started my programming journey actually had a whole entire chapter on this:

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/

The module you're looking to use is "selenium"; even though many would claim that there's better modules to use in 2022, selenium will do the job fine for your purposes.